# Citer des enregistrements de musique classique

Tags: usage, musique, citations, bibliographie

Dans une discographie propre à une œuvre donnée (donc qui dispense de préciser le compositeur, la date de composition et le nom de l’œuvre même), comment doit-on citer les différentes informations relatives à un enregistrement ?

Dans les sciences humaines, le style le plus courant est :

`<Auteur>. <Nom de l’œuvre en italique>. <Maison d’édition>, <année de publication>`.

Ce qui, adapté aux enregistrements, devrait donner quelque chose comme :

`<Chef d’orchestre> <Soliste, s’il y en a un>, <Orchestre>. <Label>, <année>`.

Mais, n’étant ni musicien ni musicologue, j’ignore si l’usage consiste aussi à noter tous les solistes ainsi que leur rôle (ou même la tessiture de leur voix).

En résumé, quel est l’usage en la matière ?

Comment: Le nom de ladite œuvre (donc nom de l'enregistrement très probablement) et de son compositeur me paraissent aussi pertinente. La combinaison Orchestre / Chef d'orchestre / Année semble suffisante pour identifier les différents solistes dans les cas les plus communs.

Comment: j'ai trouvé ca: http://www.mus.ulaval.ca/roberge/gdrm/00-essen.htm  ca répondra peut etre à ce que tu cherches...

Comment: @servabat, en effet, le nom de l’œuvre ainsi que son compositeur sont importants mais dans les cas où il est question de plusieurs œuvres à la fois. Admettons que dans le contexte, il s’agisse d’une seule et même œuvre qui revienne sans cesse, ou, mieux encore que l’on cherche à faire une liste (à puces ou numérotée, peut importe) des enregistrements d’une même œuvre. C’est de ce cas là qu’il s’agit.

Comment: Es-tu sûr que la formulation soit propre au Français? Ne serait-il pas plus judicieux de demander sur [music.stackexchange](http://music.stackexchange.com/) ?

Comment: Oui. Les usages en matière de typographie et de citation bibliographique diffèrent énormément d’une langue à l’autre et dépendent de l’usage éditorial de chaque langue. Et puis, il est d’autant moins pertinant d’aller sur music.stackexchange que je ne cherches pas à comprendre un aspect de la musique mais seulement savoir comment en *parler* en langue française.

Answer (score 1):

D'après [cette page d'un enseignant de français](http://users.skynet.be/fralica/refer/theorie/annex/refbibl.htm#disque), se basant sur une page de l'[Observatoire Musical Français](https://web.archive.org/web/20061123033758/http://www.omf.paris4.sorbonne.fr/omf-articles.php3?id_rubrique=98&id_article=540) (archive) ne mentionnant en fait que la citation de chansons, la norme serait pour les œuvres classiques de citer d'abord le compositeur, le titre/opus, **puis le(s) soliste(s), l'orchestre et le chef d'orchestre** :

> Johannes BRAHMS, *Concerto pour piano n°1 en ré mineur op. 15 - III : Rondo. Allegro non troppo*. Vladimir Ashkenazy, piano. Orchestre du Concertgebouw d'Amsterdam, Bernard Haitink (DECCA 4100092).

Je ne suis pas spécialiste en la matière, mais après quelques recherches, il ne semble pas y avoir énormément de normes quant aux références d'enregistrements d’œuvres classiques. En l'absence de standard, et en particulier ici où vous semblez avoir besoin d'une présentation particulière (l'œuvre et le compositeur étant *a priori* connus), je pense que vous devez développer votre propre syntaxe *ad hoc* et maintenir une cohérence d'ensemble.

Answer (score -1):

Pour les documents officiels, on se base sur une norme AFNOR adaptée de l'ISO 690.

Il y a une [page Wikipédia FR](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikip%C3%A9dia:Conventions_sur_les_titres_d%27%C5%93uvres_de_musique_classique) qui l'explique mieux que je ne saurais le faire.

Comment: Cette norme est faite pour noter les noms d’œuvres originales, non les **enregistrements**. Que l’on s’entende, le problème ici n’est pas la présentation du compositeur, de la date de composition ou du nom de l’œuvre mais des différents **enregistrements** d’une œuvre.